# What's the "android:layout_column" attribute?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

The ***main.xml*** file code:

```
<TableRow 
android:id="@+id/TableRow01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
    android:text="User" 
    android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

    <EditText 
    android:text="" 
    android:id="@+id/username" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    ></EditText>

    <TextView 
    android:text="Test" 
    android:id="@+id/usernameTest" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    ></TextView>

</TableRow>

<TableRow 
android:id="@+id/TableRow05" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <TextView 
    android:text="Hobby" 
    android:id="@+id/hobby" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

    <CheckBox 
    android:text="A" 
    android:id="@+id/reading" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    ></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox 
    android:text="B" 
    android:id="@+id/swimming" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    ></CheckBox>


</TableRow>
```

I have looked in the official android docs, from which I learned, `android:layout_column` means ***The index of the column in which this child should be.*** I've set the attribute on the two `CheckBox`:  `android:layout_column = "1"`, so I thought the two `CheckBox` should both in the second column(index: 1). but to my amazement, the first `CheckBox` is in the second column, and the second `CheckBox` is in the third column , just as you can see below:
[image]

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put two `Views` in the same column. The first `CheckBox` goes in the column 1 as you set it with `android:layout_column = "1"`  and the second CheckBox is automatically placed in the 2th column.

**Edit:** If you do want your checkboxes in the same column you could just wrap them with a `LinearLayout` and then set the `android:layout_column = "1"` for that `LinearLayout`.